# Using Google Docs and Google Spreadsheet APIs for Android

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I am planning on using the Google Documents List, and Google Documents Spreadsheet API's for uploading a database from my app to a spreadsheet online and then editing it.

I just wanted to know if these API's would be the right approach for using Google docs as an online storage space for the data that I have collected in my app.

I was hoping that I could just get feedback from some of you who might have experience with this.

The links for both API's are listed below:

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(Dec 2016-Feb 2017)** Various parts of this question are now out-of-date as: 1) [GData APIs](http://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) (including both the Documents List and Spreadsheets APIs) are the previous generation of Google APIs. While not all GData APIs have been deprecated, [all **modern** Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis) do **not** use [the Google Data protocol](http://developers.google.com/gdata); 2) the Google Documents List API has been [replaced](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2012/09/retiring-google-documents-list-api-v3.html) (and [shut down](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2014/12/reminder-to-migrate-to-updated-google.html) in 2015) by the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) (mobile developers have a specific [Google Drive Android API](http://developers.google.com/drive/android)), 3) Google [released](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/05/apps-dev-sheets-api.html) a new [Google Sheets API v4](http://developers.google.com/sheets) (not GData) in 2016, and 4) [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/studio) is now the preferred IDE over Eclipse.

In order to use Google APIs, you need to get the [Google APIs Client Library for Android](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android) (or for more general Java, the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java)). Now for some examples... here's the [Android quickstart code sample](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android) as well as the more general [Java Quickstart code sample](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) for the Sheets API. Can't hurt to pass along the [JavaDocs reference for the Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/) either.

If you're not "allergic" to Python, I've also made several videos with more "real-world" examples using the Sheets API (non-mobile though):

- [Migrating SQL data to a Sheet](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html))
- [Formatting text using the Sheets API](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/formatting-cells-with-the-google-sheets-api.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/09/formatting-cells-in-google-sheets-with.html))
- [Generating slides from spreadsheet data](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/11/generating-slides-from-spreadsheet-data.html))

The latest API provides features not available in older releases, namely giving developers programmatic **document**-oriented access to a Sheet as if you were using the user interface (create frozen rows, perform cell formatting, resizing rows/columns, adding pivot tables, creating charts, etc.) However, to perform **file**-level access such as imports & exports, you would use the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) instead -- for mobile, there's a specific [Google Drive Android API](http://developers.google.com/drive/android).

But based on your use-case, I don't believe you need the Drive API (nor the deprecated Documents List API) unless you need to perform file operations like searching or those I described just above. You can just use the Sheets API to "upload a database from your [Android] app to a spreadsheet online and then edit it." My one video above on "migrating SQL data to a Sheet" should give you enough pseudocode (that's what Python is, isn't it?) to write your app.

To learn more about how to use Google APIs, check out the variety of Google developer videos ([series 1](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq) and [series 2](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJJFx_MVCQJ7eWF3gDxkl)) I'm producing (heads-up mostly Python or JavaScript).

Answer (score 8):

For accessing Google APIs on the android platform, the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client) is the way to go.

It includes [sample apps](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs) for the Documents and Spreadsheet APIs.

Comment: There is not an example of the spreadsheets api at that link.

Comment: @Patrick - exactly my thoughts. Everyone says use the new API, yet there are no SpreadSheet examples. And I cannot find a single SpreadSheet class in the new Google apis, I can in the old gdata apis though.

Comment: I added a new answer to this Q that should resolve some of the comments here.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't like Google's api lib for java. I honestly think you are better off using scribe and jackson to deserialize the feeds. We made a hello world. It includes calls with openid and oauth to spreadsheet feeds and deserialization template. Hope it helps.

[link](https://github.com/claytantor/marketplace-helloworld-spring3)