# Using Spreadsheet as Databases for android apps as a centralised database

Tags: android, database, spreadsheet

I have a app which needs a centralised Database.So I am planning to use `Google Spread Sheets`.
I have gone through [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), 
but I really did not understand much in it.
So is there any example codes available please suggest.

Comment: I'm still workin on it dono how to use the Google API itself i have the libraries downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related SO question: [Using Google Docs and Google Spreadsheet APIs for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6408580/1431750). There's an [answer which links to projects with API docs and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409252/1431750).

> So is there any example codes available please suggest.
>
> I'm still workin on it dono how to use the Google API itself i have
> the libraries downloaded

Why not also google for some examples - http://www.google.com/search?q=android+google+spreadsheet+example?